# My login modal is working incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm making a modal with bootstrap.
I'm new to Web Engineering and need some help.
My modal is supposed to have two dynamic tabs, one for Sign In, and one for Sign Up. I wanted to use two concepts in one task so I'm using dynamic tabs along with modal.

Please let me know what's wrong in it. The sign in tab works fine, but when I click on sign up, it shows the sign up credentials below the fixated div and items of sign in above, rather than overwriting it like it happens in dynamic tabs.

It looks like this: [Modal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdfDf.png)

```
  <style>
  .modal-header, h4, .close {
      background-color: #5cb85c;
      color:white !important;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 30px;
  }
  .modal-footer {
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>



<div class="container">
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="myBtn">Login</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Login</h4>
        </div>

                <div class="bs-example bs-example-tabs">
                <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#signin" data-toggle="tab">Sign In</a></li>
                  <li class=""><a href="#signup" data-toggle="tab">Register</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
               <div class="imgcontainer">

      <img src="img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar" style="height:200px; width:200px; align:center; margin-left: 220px">
    </div>

        <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
      <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="signin">

      <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Username</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usrname" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="psw"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Password</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="psw" placeholder="Enter password">
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="" checked>Remember me</label>
            </div>

           <!-- Login button-->
           <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="signin"></label>
                  <div class="controls">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Login</button>
         </div></div>
                 </form>

               <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>
          <p>Not a member? <a href="#">Sign Up</a></p>
          <p>Forgot <a href="#">Password?</a></p>
        </div>

      <!-- MODAL SIGN UP-->
       <div class="tab-pane fade" id="signup">
        <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Username</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usrname" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="psw"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Password</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="psw" placeholder="Enter password">
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="" checked>Remember me</label>
            </div>

             <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="reenterpassword">Re-Enter Password:</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input id="reenterpassword" class="form-control" name="reenterpassword" type="password" placeholder="********" class="input-large" required="">
                  </div>
                </div>

             <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="humancheck">Humanity Check:</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <label class="radio inline" for="humancheck-0">
                      <input type="radio" name="humancheck" id="humancheck-0" value="robot" checked="checked">I'm a Robot</label>
                    <label class="radio inline" for="humancheck-1">
                      <input type="radio" name="humancheck" id="humancheck-1" value="human">I'm Human</label>
                  </div>
                </div>

                            <!-- Button -->
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="confirmsignup"></label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <button id="confirmsignup" name="confirmsignup" class="btn btn-success">Sign Up</button>
                  </div>
                </div>

                   </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

       </form>
       </div>


      </div>

        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal();
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to specify some kind of flag to switch between the sections.

Answer (score 0):

you must provide "show" or "hide" parameter inside modal function.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
    });
});
</script>
```

// optional
hide modal on button click

`$("#myModal").modal("hide");`

Answer (score 0):

you're putting the signup div inside of the signing div :

```
<div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="signup">
        <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Username</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usrname" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="psw"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Password</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="psw" placeholder="Enter password">
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="" checked="">Remember me</label>
            </div>

             <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="reenterpassword">Re-Enter Password:</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input id="reenterpassword" class="form-control" name="reenterpassword" type="password" placeholder="********" required="">
                  </div>
                </div>

             <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="humancheck">Humanity Check:</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <label class="radio inline" for="humancheck-0">
                      <input type="radio" name="humancheck" id="humancheck-0" value="robot" checked="checked">I'm a Robot</label>
                    <label class="radio inline" for="humancheck-1">
                      <input type="radio" name="humancheck" id="humancheck-1" value="human">I'm Human</label>
                  </div>
                </div>

                            <!-- Button -->
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="confirmsignup"></label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <button id="confirmsignup" name="confirmsignup" class="btn btn-success">Sign Up</button>
                  </div>
                </div>

                   </form></div><div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="signin">

      <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Username</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usrname" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="psw"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Password</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="psw" placeholder="Enter password">
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="" checked="">Remember me</label>
            </div>

           <!-- Login button-->
           <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="signin"></label>
                  <div class="controls">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Login</button>
         </div></div>
                 </form>

               <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>
          <p>Not a member? <a href="#">Sign Up</a></p>
          <p>Forgot <a href="#">Password?</a></p>
        </div>

      <!-- MODAL SIGN UP-->

        </div>
      </div>
```

you need to put the signup div outside of the signing div :